# Плагин jscrollpane. Не прокручивать скролл глобального окна

Tags: jscrollpane, jquery, javascript

Добрый день!
При прокручивании скролла маленького блока и достижении низа в этом блоке - начинает прокручиваться скролл глобального окна(браузера). Как сделать так, чтобы окно браузера не прокручивалось, конечно же при наведенной мышке на маленьком окне
Спасибо!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ - это устанавливать свойство **overflow: hidden;** документу, при наведении на блок со скроллом. [Смотрим пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/dgxrr04u/).

```
var body = $('body');
$('.scrolling-block').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        body.css('overflow', 'hidden');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        body.css('overflow', 'auto');
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Еще один из вариантов $('.scrollpane').jScrollPane({
            autoReinitialise: true
        }).bind(
            'mousewheel',
            function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        );

Comment: @idd, возможно, что с плагином вы получите нужный эффект, но тогда не забудьте добавить событие под FireFox, иначе там работать не будет:

    $('.scrollpane').jScrollPane({ autoReinitialise: true })
      .bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
      });

Хотя на мой взгляд, логичней было бы использовать **e.stopPropagation();**